# More than 2000 watches in AngularJS Page?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I would like to know is it possible to create data table with about 300 columns and 300 rows and all cells will be editable so I need to have two way data binding.

All I have seen on web is that if there are more than 2000 watches on a page that Angular starts to get sluggish. So what are the best practices for this kind of requirenment if you are using AngularJS ?

Thanks,
Maverick

Comment: Wich version of AngualrJS are you using?
Starting with 1.3 (Still RC) you can use one-time bindings, that probably will allow your flags to get set.
However, with a table this big, I would opt for a form of pagination, and put only the visible part in the DOM. that way, you still can use the easy 2-way binding, and have good perfomance.

Comment: actually I thought about virtual scrolling ( as pagination is not an option) but even in case of virtual scrolling I would end up eventually to more than 2000 watches. And with 1.3 RC , with one way binding , there wont be any watches ?

Comment: Really... I've spend a lot of time on this kind of problem. And if you exclude infinite scroll and bindonce and review of your UI... it is like you are asking for a water that is cold and very hot at the same time.

Comment: @Maverick, you can do pagination on data you have already available in you memory, why do you feel this is not an option?
And do you really need the 2-way binding on every column? 
If pagination is not an option, and one-time bindings can't be used either, you need to tell your users they need fast computer with a large amount of memory. 
a 300x300 grid will have 90.000 cels, and with a couple of directives in each cell you will have at least 180.000 watches. 
No matter what you use, it will be sluggish.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the [bindonce](https://github.com/Pasvaz/bindonce) module which permits you optimize/desactivate watchers if you don't need it. (with little effort, you could still activate watchers only when needed, when trying to edit a specific cell)

Without this, yeah It will be a pain to have a table of this size, but even without angularjs I would reconsider creating such a heavy table (ergonomy/readability, low-perf user devices)

Hope this helps

Comment: I also need to apply different colors to some columns and rows on the basis data flags. So using bindonce is not an option. Table always have to be two way data binded so on change of data flags , table colors could be updated.

Comment: ok so 300rows * 300cells = 90000 cells dual-binded ? you can forget that :o

Comment: So what are recommended approaches for development of this kind of component in HTML/JavaScript ? jQuery ?

Comment: I personnaly wouldn't recommended any approach as it don't seems to me a realistic feature if you want dual-binded realtime cells. I'll let other people help you. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

My initial thought would be using **[ReactJS](http://facebook.github.io/react/)** with AngularJS. ReactJS is not too completed, you can learn from their offical website. Two way binding won't be directly supported by ReactJS, you would need to add some code to make it supportable.

Comment: I think ReactJS would only improve the rendering time and I think it also supports one way binding only. My problem is I always want my table to listen for data changes as user can not only edit the cell value but table also reflect back the changes by apply colors on different rows and column on the data flags bind-ed to it.